# Generate SQL Scripts from SSDT project (VS2013 / TFS2012 [MSBuild]) for use in InstallShield 2013 Pro

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, installshield, sql-server-data-tools

We are using Visual Studio 2013 with SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) to develop our database projects. When TFS builds the database project, the "_Create.sql" file generated requires SQLCMD mode and contains variables. InstallShield 2013 does not appear to support SQLCMD mode (investigation points to InstallShield using ODBC and/or OLEDB drivers to execute SQL scripts).

Essentially, I need our TFS build process to create a "standard" SQL script, compatible with InstallShield 2013 Professional. Has anybody had any experience with this... and if so, please can you provide some pointers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just create a step in installshield to either call sqlcmd.exe or even better sqlpackage.exe and pass in the dacpac?

Comment: Unfortunately, Management Studio will not be installed on the machine where the InstallShield will be running. In some cases, the installer will only run the SQL script to create a database on a remote server. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: You can distribute sqlpackage.exe so could deploy from dacpac (you could xcopy sqlpackage to temp dir) - if you didn't want a command prompt you could use dacfx api to publish dacpac from .net code

Comment: Looking at this page (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/f910f42f-a4e6-472b-8f7d-485f8d273d06/sqlpackageexe-redistribution) it would seem it isn't a simple xcopy deployment due to dependencies on other assemblies. What experience have you had with doing an xcopy deployment of sqlpackage.exe; did you have to xcopy the other DLLs mentioned on that page; is it legal to distribute outside of the MS installer?

Comment: yes, I distribute the dll's that are needed and have a simle wrapper to call the deploy form my own code. Internally I include sqlpackage.exe with a folder with all its dependencies (just copy the whole folder sqlpackage.exe is in) - I don't distribute sqlpackage externally outside of the msi and you should get your legal people to check the license as to whether you are able to (I certainly wouldn't take advice on stack overflow!). There is more info here about which files you need http://www.anupkumarsharma.com/2013/10/deploy-dacpac-in-sqlserver2008-r2-using.html